# Notepad to VIM copy/paste code

Tags: php, vim, heroku, vi

I want to copy code from notepad and want to paste it in heroku VIM.I tried many methods and done alot of googling . How to achieve this ??

Comment: `heroku vim` yields `!    'vim' is not a heroku command.` Please clarify what you mean by “heroku VIM”.

Answer (score 3):

If you want random strangers to help you, you should be a little more helpful yourself. What methods did you try? What was the outcome? What worked? What didn't?

Assuming you are connected to a remote server via SSH, the usual method is to paste with a click on your mousewheel or use your terminal emulator's "paste" function. The result is often horrible and you must issue `:set paste` in Vim before pasting, and `:set nopaste` after pasting.

See `:h pastetoggle` for a more convenient solution.

Answer (score 1):

I share others' confusion about what you are asking, but a common complaint about Vim is that by default it does not share the system clipboard. By default yanking and putting uses the unnamed register, but you can specify a different register if you wish.

The system clipboard is accessed via the `+` or `*` registers (depending on the system). On Windows (as far as I know) they are equivalent. For a one-off pasting operation you can specify one of these registers to paste from using `"+p` or `"*p` instead of the usual `p`. (Note that the `"+` or `"*` specifiers can also be used for yanking, and several other Normal mode operations.)

If you ALWAYS want to use the system clipboard, you can set the option

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

However, this may not have anything to do with your question.